# Remove all occurrences of largest item using list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use list comprehension to define a Haskell function designated as `ted` that takes a list of items of type class `Ord`.  The function `ted` shall remove all occurrences of the largest item in the list. In case the given list is empty, `ted` shall just return the empty list.

This is my code

```
import Data. List
import Data.Function

rmax :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
Prelude> [a | a<- as]
[a | a <- as, a % 2 == 0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [a | a <- as]
[a | a <- as, a % 2 == 0]

Comment: Should work great as long as the largest number is even and no other numbers are.

Comment: How do I do this if the largest number is not even, or its string or an empty set?

Comment: I would find the largest element in one pass and then pull all elements that are smaller in a second pass (this would be your list comprehension).

Answer (score 4):

```
module Main where

list :: [Int]
list = [5,8,6,3,8]
--list = []
--list = [8]

ted :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
ted as = [a | a<-as, a /= (maximum as)]

main :: IO ()
main =  putStrLn $ show $ ted list
```

Output:

```
[5,6,3]
```

Comment: `[a | let x = maximum as, a<-as, a /= x]` is better. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a single pass over the list:

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty (..))

removeMax :: Ord a => NonEmpty a -> [a]
removeMax xs@(hd :| _) =
  let (res, greatest) =
    foldr
      (\x (tl, m) -> (if x == greatest then tl else x : tl, max x m))
      ([], hd)
      xs
   in res
```

This is called ["tying the knot"](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tying_the_Knot).

Comment: This might be a solution. But this is not list comprehension. You may improve your answer to answer the question correctly.